# Repository and entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6.1 and now I write a data layer in my project. A have classes like that

```
[Table("Name")]
public partial class Name
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

and repositories that were automatically generated like that

```
public class NameRepository : INameRepository
{

    NameContext context = new NameContext();

    public IQueryable<Name> All
    {
        get { return context.Names; }
    }

    public IQueryable<Name> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Name, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<Name> query = context.Names;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }

    public Name Find(int id)
    {
        return context.Names.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(Name name)
    {
        if (name.Id == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.Names.Add(name);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(name).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var name = context.Names.Find(id);
        context.Names.Remove(name);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface INameRepository : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<Name> All { get; }
    IQueryable<Name> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Name, object>>[] includeProperties);
    Name Find(int id);
    void InsertOrUpdate(Name name);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Save();
}
```

Context is also automatically generated. But when i work with application

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = new Name();
    name.Books = new List<Book>();
    name.FirstName = "max";
    name.Patronymic = "A";
    name.SecondName = "G";
    name.Profiles = new List<Profile>();
    var nameRepository = new NameRepository();
    nameRepository.InsertOrUpdate(name);
    nameRepository.Save();
    var names = nameContext.All;

}
```

I don't have a database. But this application run and return me my last name, that I have added. As I understand that if database doesn't exist it can be created by entity framework. But it doesn't. So my question is "How I can create this database?". But, maybe, I have been mistaken and entity framework can't create the database?

Comment: What do you mean "I can't work with it"?

Comment: Sounds like you want to change the database that your application points to?  As mentioned by @DStanley, please detail exactly what you mean by "And after I closed application, I can't work with it"?

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing this link could be useful :

[EF Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)

The section **Where is my data ?** is what you are looking for I'm guessing.